# ¿Como mostrar y ocultar un div sin javascript?

Tags: html, css, amp

quiero ocultar y mostrar un div usando un boton solo con html y css, sin java Script

```
<div id="ocultar">
     <!-- content(); -->
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con etiquetas de css como `:hover` [aqui un ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n5fzB/2/)

Comment: Hola @NicolasOñate como aria para usar solo un boton y sin `hover`

Comment: Pues ya eso, sin javascript escapa de mi entendimiento, ya que es lo mas sencillo, tal vez puedas usar scss

Comment: ¿Por qué no quieres usar JavaScript? Está para hacer este tipo de cosas...

Comment: @ordago por que estoy haciendo una web en **AMP** y no acepta javascript por eso quiero hacerlo con css puro o html

Comment: Si es así, te recomiendo que añadas el tag `amp` a la pregunta (o los tags que puedan estar relacionados: por ejemplo email?), ya que puede haber gente que pilote de esos temas y esté suscrita a esos tags. Así tu pregunta llega a más gente.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML completo de tu página? Según la posición en la que se encuentren los elementos sería posible realizarlo únicamente con CSS.

Comment: Se podría hacer a través de `:target` o a través de `:focus`. Dependiendo de la estructura de tu página y tus elementos de HTML

Answer (score 5):

Eso se realiza mediante el evento on=tap

Te dejo este código con ejemplo de mostrar y ocultar

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Eventos con Botones</title>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/difros/pen/zYxJRyM">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  
</head>
  
<body>
 <button id="btn_ver" class="button" on="tap:div_contenido.show">Ver Contenido</button> 
<button id="btn_ocultar" class="button" on="tap:div_contenido.hide">Ocultar Contenido</button>
   
<br><br><div id="div_contenido" hidden>Contenido</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y también lo podés ver aquí: [Probalo en Codepen](https://codepen.io/difros/pen/zYxJRyM)

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo el código y luego te explico:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #ocultar {
            display: none;
        }
        
        #chk:checked + #ocultar {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <button><label for="chk">clic</label></button>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <div id="ocultar">
      <!-- content(); -->
     Contenido
    </div>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

En resumen para poder mostrar y ocultar un div (o lo que sea) con css has de usar la pseudoclase ::checked sobre un input de tipo checkbox:

1. Crea el `<input type="checkbox" id="chk">` justo encima del div que quieras hacer aparecer y desaparecer
2. Relacionamos el botón con el checkbox a través de una etiqueta `<label for="chk">`
3. mediante el selector `#chk:checked + #ocultar` le decimos que cuando el checkbox esté chequeado el hermano siguiente #ocultar (eso se lo decimos con el +) se muestre.
4. Al input le puedes poner un `display: none;` para que no se vea el "cuadrito" y es igual de efectivo.